# How to use the `.prop ` values for multiple elements

Tags: jquery

how to use the `.prop` to get value for multiple elements. `.Prop` works fine only for the first element.

```
var cursorPosition = $('.show1').prop("selectionStart");**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want an array

Comment: No. I'm having a table in form which has multiple rows. "('.show1')" is a class name for first column. I need to use the prop  for the multiple elements in show1 class."Prop" works fine only for the first element.

Comment: It all depends where you're using the prop .. . with the right `jQuery` method you can use `$(this).prop(.....)` as you iterate through the collection, unless you need an array of all the props for all table rows.

Comment: You have to iterate the collection .... almost all jQuery getters can only return values of one element at a time. Please explain in more dteail in the question what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Can I've a link about how to iterate using collections. Plz.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution for looping through all the rows with class `show1` :

```
$(function(){
  $('.show1').each(function(){
    var cursorPosition = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
    // do something with `cursorPosition`
  })
})
```